# Typescript: How can I define a type from an string array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, types

Currently I do:

```
export const CValidEbookTypes = ['epub', 'mobi', 'pdf', 'azw3', 'txt', 'rtf'];
export type IEbookType = 'epub' | 'mobi' | 'pdf' | 'azw3' | 'txt' | 'rtf';
```

to have an array of valid book types and a typescript type, that defines them. This look quite redundant.

Is there a way to define the type using the array?
My goal is obviously to avoid writing the book type twice. So any other solution would also be welcome.

Comment: You can use `CValidEbookTypes[number]`, but you need to add `as const` after the array to infer the types as literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `as const`, typescript infers the string literals as type for `CValidEbookTypes`. Then you can use `typeof CValidEbookTypes[number]`:

```
export const CValidEbookTypes = ['epub', 'mobi', 'pdf', 'azw3', 'txt', 'rtf'] as const;
export type IEbookType = typeof CValidEbookTypes[number];
// IEbookType will be "epub" | "mobi" | "pdf" | "azw3" | "txt" | "rtf"
```